# Is plot identification question on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Although I posted a chat message in the Screening Rom [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7785063#7785063), I would like to make it a permanent meta-discussion.

---

So here is my question: **If a movie/TV show is based on a famous work by a writer and it is not revealed which specific story/novel the movie/TV show is based upon, can we ask for the original story to be identified? Maybe the community will know! Would this type of question be on-topic?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to ask is on-topic.

Comment: I think he's asking if recognizing plot elements from other media within a movie is an on-topic question. Say a movie borrows from "Tell-Tale Heart" by Poe, without attribution. Would a question to ascertain agreement of this heavily-borrowed plot be on topic?

Comment: Suppose it is written in the start of a movie `Based upon a famous novel by author X`. But it is never revealed which _novel_. So will it be on topic if I ask here which novel by author X this movie is based upon?

Comment: I've fixed the question text to align with your clarification.

Comment: I can't think of any good reaons why this would be off-topic.

Comment: @Keen, Thank you for making it more clear!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why such questions should be off-topic. Asking about the background, possible source material, or inspiration of a movie seems perfectly appropriate, no matter if you're asking *if* it is based on some other story, *which* story it is based on or in which way it deviates from its base material.

So yes, even if I wouldn't call it *"plot identification"* (which invokes false associations to a question type with entirely different quality and on-topic considerations), such questions seem perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

In essence the question comes down to "Was this based on something that came before?"

Which to me, seems like a valid question.  Maybe a good insightful answer also points out how they correlate/what differences they have from one another.